# Users can only update and delete objects tied to their account with tastypie

Tags: django, tastypie

Using tastypie, how do I only authorize authors of objects the ability to edit/delete objects they have created? For example, if user 1 created an object A, how can I make it so user 2 cannot edit or delete object A but user 1 can edit or delete object A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this cook-book entry:
http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#creating-per-user-resources

If that doesn't fit you well, there is an WIP on per-object permissions in the perms branch of tastypie repo. You might want to check that out but beware that it's not ready yet.